# Horizontally scrolling area whose visible width fills the remainder of a fluid-width page

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty standard two-column layout, but one element in the content-column needs to deliver its content in a horizontally-scrolling area whose (visible) width fills the remainder of the page, i.e. fills the width of its containing column. I can get (almost) the effect I need by setting a fixed width on the scrolling area, but I need its width to be dynamic. Can this be done with just HTML and CSS, or do I need to manually set and update its width with JS?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dux4dxmL/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Layout</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.top-menu { background-color: blue; height: 100px; color: #fff }
    td.side-content { background-color: green; width: 150px; }
    div.scrollable-area { width: 400px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap;}
    div.scrollable-area > div.content-block { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-menu">(Top menu)</div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="side-content">(Side content)</td>
          <td>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div class="scrollable-area">
              <div class="content-block">BLAH BLAH</div>
              <div class="content-block">BLAH BLAH</div>
              (ETC)
              <div class="content-block">BLAH BLAH</div>
              <div class="content-block">BLAH BLAH</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles to your table:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

You can then remove the `width` style from `div.scrollable-area`.

### Fiddle